# How does bigquery partition selection work

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm confused about BigQuery's table partitioning.

I have an example table with the following structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `MYDATASET.MYTABLE` (
    MYCOLUMN STRING
   ,MYPARTITION TIMESTAMP
    )
PARTITION BY DATE(MYPARTITION)
;
```

Then, I'm currently querying it like this:

```sql
SELECT MYCOLUMN 
FROM MYDATASET.MYTABLE 
WHERE EXTRACT(DATE FROM MYPARTITION AT TIME ZONE 'America/Sao_Paulo') = EXTRACT(DATE FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AT TIME ZONE 'America/Sao_Paulo')
```

The intended result of this query is to return all rows for the current day in a specified time zone.

Am I taking advantage of BigQuery partitioning with my current table structure and query? How BigQuery chooses which partitions to load?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you read related documentation? do you need link?

Comment: Yes, but as far as I have read it, the documentation does not clarified my question.

Comment: the simplest way to get your first question answered is just to run and see processed bytes :o)

Comment: Thank you, seems like a good sugestion. I'll try running some tests on a example dataset. But I really would like to understand how bigquery works behind the scenes, to be able to predict if my future queries will have good performance or not. If you have any link to share with me to further clarify my question I would be really glad.